# ray intersect not working in sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, webgl, raytracing

created the sphere and the plane geometry when i ignore the sphere form scene.add()
interesect work but

here is the code..
http://jsfiddle.net/praveenv29/PZeY4/

```
for ( var i = 0; i<10; i ++ ) 
        {
    var gloom = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../map_pin.png' );
materialr = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color:Math.random() * 0xffffff ,side: THREE.DoubleSide} )
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10,15,2, 2);
    var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialr);   
                object.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                object.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;


                object.position.normalize();
                object.position.multiplyScalar(125 );    

    scene.add( object );
    }
```

and once add the sphere scene intersect not working the 
( http://jsfiddle.net/praveenv29/PZeY4/1/ )

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../world.jpg'); 
materials = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color:0x000000, wireframe:true}); 

var cone = new THREE.SphereGeometry(120,25,25);

var coneMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cone,materials);

coneMesh.position.y =0;
coneMesh.rotation.set(0,0,0);   
scene.add( coneMesh );
```

tried in geometry  merge may be some properties missing????

Comment: Adding the sphere is not the problem. You are using trackball controls and orbit controls at the same time. Your ray-casting logic is buggy. You have console errors... Doing ray-casting inside the render loop is probably not a good idea. You need to simplify your code and start over.